# NServiceBus, how to MapPath

Tags: nservicebus, mappath

Trying to get the path to my "XML documentation file" on NServiceBus. Normally I would use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`, however NServiceBus doesn't use HttpContext. So the question is, how do I get a path to the "XMl doucumentation file" and other files on NServiceBus?

Thanks!

-a-

Comment: I personally haven't confirmed this but we typically go off the AppDomain: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comment, use the [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx)